# What should the editors tag used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

What differentiate the editors tag from other tags? It should be about asking for general stuff about editors (ie editor recommendation for an specific task, how to configure the default editor) or for specific editors that doesn't have their own tag (ie, how to do X in Serna (serna is an xml editor), how to configure my view in radare (a hexadecimal editor))? Should it get renamed to [text-editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors)? What is the usage of the tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors) is indeed mostly if not exclusively about text editors, as the tag wiki indicates. I think I agree with renaming to [text-editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors) — I can't think of many questions that could apply to a more general sense of “a program that modifies a file based on user interactions”.

[editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors) should only be used on the few questions that are about editors in general, as opposed to about a specific editor. If you have a question about Emacs, tag it [emacs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs). If you have a question about Serna, tag it [serna](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serna).

Here are some examples of questions that should have the [editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors) tag:

- Questions about choosing the right editor for a task.
- Questions about how (a large class of) editors work, such as [Modeless vs modal editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57705/modeless-vs-modal-editors) or [Get rid of *~ files in KDE editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55588/get-rid-of-files-in-kde-editors) or [File permissions and saving](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/file-permissions-and-saving)

Questions about transforming text should use the tag [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing), not [text-editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors), unless the question is specifically about doing the transformation interactively and not as part of a batch job.

There's a lot of cruft in the [editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors) tag, due mainly to misuse with another editor tag. There should be very few, if any, questions tagged [editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors)+[emacs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs) or [editors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors)+[vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim), etc.

Comment: What about "difference between X and Y?" which is the [most voted question in the tag](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/986/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-vim-and-emacs)?

Comment: @Braiam It's specifically about X and Y, so it should only be tagged X and Y, not [tag:editors].

Comment: No more [tag:editors]+[tag:kate].

Comment: I've gone through [tag:editors]+[tag:emacs]; only a couple of questions called for both tags. I'm leaving vi(m) to others.